# Dependency Injection of IEnumerable<IObjects> Defined by Config in ASP.NET core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I have a data service I am building in C# on ASP.NET core (at this point RC1). Its purpose is to take a collection of data requests of varying types and return a data repository object. This object is then converted to JSON and sent to the requesting page.

The sources for the data break down into a few categories and in each category, there are multiple sources for the data of differing speed and reliability.

My approach has been to follow SOLID principles as best I know how (still learning) and use Dependency Injection for creating the hierarchy of objects needed to resolve the requests and return the consolidated data.

One of the specific goals is to be able to define in the configuration (at this point appsettings.json) the collection of data routing objects and data adapter objects that will be injected into each layer. The data sources can change periodically, new sources added and I also want a system that allows mocking for tests.

I have done this by creating interfaces, IDataRouter and IDataAdapter that work uniformly across all situations.

My current challenge is to use the ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection system (or a suitable replacement) to create enumerations of IDataRouter and IDataAdapter based on the concrete implementations referenced in my config files. These would then be injected into the higher level classes and used for collecting the data requested.

Here is a general breakdown;

The DataService has one:many instances of IDataRouter as an IEnumerable. An IRequests object (is an IEnumerable) is taken in and each IRequest is sent to the appropriate IDataRouter for further processing.

Each IDataRouter has one:many instances of IDataAdapter as an IEnumerable. Each IDataAdapter is capable of handling a specific type of IRequest.

The requests move down from the DataService to the DataRouters then to the DataAdapters where the data is sourced. The data then flows back up through the chain and gets consolidated into one repository at the DataService level before getting converted to JSON and sent to the requestor.

My specific question is how do I use the ASP.NET core DI system to build the IEnumerable and the IEnumerable enumerations to be passed to the DataService and DataRouters. They each need to contain the list of concrete implementations I specify in the config files.

Here is the current DataService constructor;

```
public DataService(IRequests requests, IEnumerable<IDataRouters> routers)
{
_requests = requests;
_routers = routers;
}
```

This will likely get converted to;

```
public class DataServiceOptions : IDataServiceOptions
{
    public IRequests requests { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IDataRouters> routers { get; set; }
}

public DataService(IOptions<IDataServiceOptions> optionsAccessor)
{
    _requests = optionsAccessor.value.requests;
    _routers = optionsAccessor.value.routers;
}
```

A very similar structure needs to be implemented for passing the IEnumerable to the IDataRouters. Each IDataRouter will need a different collection of specific concrete IDataAdapters. All of these need to be specified in the editable config source (file.)

Comment: Can you provide the config file structure?

Comment: I am using a standard appsettings.json file for the configuration. I can easily create the config settings needed to support this, including enumerations of data under a setting key. The problem is getting the objects built and associated properly in the ASP.NET DI system.
A good example is here http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html

Comment: MaKCbIMKo I can create some mocked up settings for you if it would help, but at this point I am just planning to create the settings to support what I need to do in the ASP.NET core DI system.
The settings would mainly be a name for a concrete implementation of a DataRouter with a list of DataAdapters that should be injected into it. Each setting would also have a small amount of instance specific data such as endpoints and user ID for connecting.

Comment: If you're keen on keeping your code SOLID, you should *not* depend on `IOptions<T>` as explained [here](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/143#issuecomment-155029876).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I am misunderstanding.. Can you not do this with a factory?

Create a factory class:

```
public class DataRoutersFactory : IDataRoutersFactory
{
      private readonly IConfiguration _config;

      public DataRoutersFactory(IConfiguration config)
      {
           _config = config;
      }

      public IEnumerable<IDataRouters> CreateDataRouters()
      {
          // TODO:- use whatever logic here to read _config and build the data routers to return.
      }
}
```

Then in your services, rather than injecting `IEnumerable<IDataRouters>`, inject the `IDataRoutersFactory` instead, and use that to get the routers.

For unit testing, you can mock `IDataRoutersFactory` to return whatever routers you want at test time.